# Getting wrong video time result as input bar change

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

First of all, I don't know if this problem is being caused by Javascript or CSS. I have a small piece of code that when user mouse hover the inputbar, it will show the respective video time.

I'm using this formula => `((user mouseX position / input width) * total video seconds)`
When I place the mouse over the input bar, the respective time appears, but when I click, the time is different. I don't know if this is a JS or CSS bug.

Check my code =>

```js
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   showTooltip(e);
});

document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
   document.getElementById('video').currentTime = document.getElementById('slider').value
   document.getElementById('text').innerText = CurrentTime(document.getElementById('video').currentTime);
});

function CurrentTime(v) {
    let hrs = Math.floor(v / 3600);
    let mins = Math.floor(v / 60) % 60;
    let secs = Math.floor(v) % 60;
    let ret = "";
    if (hrs > 0) {
         ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  }
  ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  ret += "" + secs;
  return ret;
}
            
function showTooltip(e) {
    // ((user mouseX position / input width) * total video seconds)
    let aa = (e.offsetX / e.target.clientWidth) * (e.target.getAttribute('max'));
       slidertitle.innerText = CurrentTime(aa);
}

let left = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    let x = ((e.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - left) + 'px';
  slidertitle.style.left = (x);
}
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
#slidertitle {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#text {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#container:hover > #slidertitle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video id="video" controls class="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4"></video>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="887" step="0.01" id="slider" value="0"/>
  <p id="slidertitle"></p>
  <p id="text">--</p>
</div>
```

[image: Wrong result vs expected result]

Note that the problem isn't related to `CurrentTime` function since it's making the right math converting seconds to hh:mm:ss. I don't know if the problem is inside `showTooltip(e)` or CSS itself. Can you help me? I'm spending some hours trying to fix this, but no success...

Thank you very much.

Comment: No one? Is it an HTML5 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the reason that range slider has some more extended margin or border(but not actually a css margin or border), the JS offset gives exact distance by including them as well.
But the value of slider is numerical without the margin or border.

**You can't calculate this margin/border,at the edges**, that's the problem.
The **ONLY SOLUTION** to this is, setting the value of slider= extended value detected on hover.
This is *not Ideal*, but *only possible,better solution*.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35632660/14862885), just hope for future updates by html,css,js, that helps you,till then follow this

```js
var valueHover = 0;
function calcSliderPos(e) {
   // ((user mouseX position / input width) * total video seconds)
  return (e.offsetX / e.target.clientWidth) *  parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('max'),10);
}

document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  valueHover = calcSliderPos(e).toFixed(2);

  //value max,min limit
  valueHover= valueHover>e.target.getAttribute('max')?e.target.getAttribute('max'):valueHover;
  valueHover= valueHover<0?0:valueHover;

  //show tooltip
  showTooltip(e);
  document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  // THE ONLY SOLUTION
  e.target.value = valueHover;

  // just your code,no edits here
  document.getElementById('video').currentTime = valueHover
  document.getElementById('text').innerText = CurrentTime(document.getElementById('video').currentTime);
    
  });
});

document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // THE ONLY SOLUTION
  e.target.value = valueHover;

  // just your code,no edits here
  document.getElementById('video').currentTime = valueHover
  document.getElementById('text').innerText = CurrentTime(document.getElementById('video').currentTime);
});



function CurrentTime(v) {
   let hrs = Math.floor(v / 3600);
   let mins = Math.floor(v / 60) % 60;
   let secs = Math.floor(v) % 60;
   let ret = "";
   if (hrs > 0) {
        ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
 }
 ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
 ret += "" + secs;
 return ret;
}
           
function showTooltip(e) {

    slidertitle.innerText = CurrentTime(valueHover);
}

let left = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
   let x = ((e.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - left) + 'px';
 slidertitle.style.left = (x);
}
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
#slidertitle {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#text {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#container:hover > #slidertitle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video id="video" controls class="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4"></video>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="887" step="0.01" id="slider" value="0"/>
  <p id="slidertitle"></p>
  <p id="text">--</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you got answer,please mark it as correct answer(green tick)